# pass connection from personal laptop through working computer that use VPN

Tags: linux, windows, networking, vpn, connection

currently I'm a consulting in development for a company, the company give me one of their computer only on Windows that use a VPN to access to their resources. I'm very bothered to use Windows instead Linux.
I work from my home with the company computer and i'm asking myself if it's possible to pass the connection from my personal laptop on Linux through the windows computer network that use the VPN ? (using the VPN directly on my personal computer is not possible)

thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you will have to make your work computer behave like a (virtual) router.
This will depend on the kind of privileges you have on your work computer.
There's an option in windows to share your internet connection via hotspot or an ethernet connection.
Here are some links that could be of help.
Again, this depends on the kinds of privileges you have.
https://support.cyberghostvpn.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002698345-How-to-share-a-VPN-connection-over-Wi-Fi-on-Windows-10
https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Windows/1441319672/Share-VPN-via-a-mobile-hotspot-on-Windows-10.htm